# a simple python code that astonishingly ignores if condition & statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a really simple code here. But the problem is really bothering me. In line no 7, there is a if-condition; astonishingly this if condition is never addressed!
I ran the program and checked multiple times using python version 2.7. It behaves as if the if-condition and its statements (along with break) is inside the comment and is simply ignored.

```
from random import randint
random_number = randint(1, 10)
guesses_left = 3
while (guesses_left>=1):
    print (random_number)
    guess = raw_input('Guess ?')      
    if guess == random_number: #this statement is never checked?
        print ('You win!')
        break
    guesses_left -= 1 
else:
    print ('You lose.')
```

Comment: `guess` is a string and `random_number` is an integer. They will never be equal. Use `guess = int(raw_input('Guess ?'))`.

Comment: Thank you for rectifying such silly mistake. Yes, now the code runs perfectly

Comment: @Matthias Wouldn't it be better to convert `random_number` to a string, then there can't be an exception thrown?

Comment: @PeterWood: In my opinion it should throw an exception. Based on that knowledge one can start to expand the code to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered that `random_number` is an integer, while `raw_input()` returns a string? This means `guess` is also a string. Try converting the variables to the same type!

Since the types differ, the values are not equal, even though they may appear to be so when printed. In other words 3 != "3".

Comment: And what has `guesses_left` to do with this?

Comment: Ah, that's a typo on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if guess == random_number: #this statement is never checked?
```

It *is* being checked, but it’s just *always* false.

`guess` is a *string* since it comes from `raw_input` but `random_number` is an int coming from `randint`. Since a string can never be equal to an int, the expression is always false.

You need to convert the input into an int first: `int(guess)`. But make sure you check for errors when the user does not enter a number.

Comment: Thank you for rectifying such silly mistake. Yes, now the code runs perfectly.